# Service and data access layer with stripes and mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, service, layer, stripes

i want to use stripes in our new project.
This will take care of the presentation layer. We want to use Mongo as our database.So what should i use in the service layer and data access layer?

Need to develop the whole stack as soon as possible.

If we write a simple data access layer for Mongo DB, can i directly call this custom data access layer from stripes ActionBean class?

Please advise.

Comment: No need to write a simple data access layer, Morphia provides DAO access to MongoDB, good stuff: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

Comment: So stripes<->spring<->morphia<->mongoDB is fine, isn't it?

Comment: I would assume Spring will work fine, although I prefer Google Guice, as it's XML free and easier to work with. http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Comment: See also Stripes-guice: http://bgoodin.github.com/stripes-guice/ This is a small Stripes extension, that can also easily build by your self though.

Comment: Thanks Kdeveloper, it was really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can directly call to the driver from the ActionBean, or create a DAO/Services layer to abstract the business logic.